# Scoping for temporary type variables

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a large number of in place [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.0.1) functions of the type

```
f :: (M.MVector v r, PrimMonad m) => 
     v (PrimState m) r -> v (PrimState m) r -> m ()
```

These functions mostly work in-place, so it is convenient to have their argument be a mutable vector so that I can compose, iterate, etc. However, at the top level, I only want to work with immutable "Haskell"/pure vectors.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, 
             ScopedTypeVariables, 
             MultiParamTypeClasses, 
             FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Vector.Generic as V hiding (eq)
import Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as M
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive

f :: (M.MVector v r, PrimMonad m) => 
     v (PrimState m) r -> v (PrimState m) r -> m ()
f vIn vOut = do val <- M.read vIn 0
                M.write vOut 0 val

applyFunc :: (M.MVector v r, PrimMonad m, V.Vector v' r, v ~ Mutable v') => 
             (v (PrimState m) r -> v (PrimState m) r -> m ()) -> v' r -> v' r
applyFunc g x = runST $ do
                    y <- V.thaw x
                    g y y -- LINE 1
                    V.unsafeFreeze y

topLevelFun :: (V.Vector v r) => r -> v r
topLevelFun a =
    let x = V.replicate 10 a
    in applyFunc f x -- LINE 2
```

The code as written results in an error on LINE 1:

```
Could not deduce (m ~ ST s)
   Expected type: ST s ()
   Actual type: m ()
   in the return type of g, LINE 1
```

Commenting out LINE 1 results in the error on LINE 2:

```
Ambiguous type variable `m0' in the constraint:
    (PrimMonad m0) arising from a use of `applyFun'
```

I've tried a variety of explicit typing (using ScopedTypeVariables, explicit foralls, etc) but haven't found a way to fix the first error. For the LINE 1 error, it seems that `m` should simply be inferred to be `ST s` since I'm in a `runST`.

For the LINE 2 error (with LINE 1 commented out), the only thing I've come up with that works is

```
class Fake m v where
    kindSig :: m a -> v b c

instance Fake m v

topLevelFun :: forall m v v' r . (V.Vector v' r, M.MVector v r, PrimMonad m, Fake m v, v ~ Mutable v') => r -> v' r
topLevelFun a =
    let x = V.replicate 10 a
    in applyFunc (f::Transform m v r)  x -- LINE 2
```

which is obviously unsatisfactory: I have to create a fake class, with an even more pointless method whose only job is to demonstrate the kinds of the class arguments. Then I create a generic instance for everything so that I can have `m` in scope in `topLevelFun`, so that I can add a constraint and cast `f`. There has GOT to be a better way.

I could be doing a wide variety of things wrong here, so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: `applyFunc` promises to work for any `PrimMonad m` the _caller_ chooses, but then `runST $ do ...` forces `m` to be `ST s`. You can fix that by stating that `g` works for any `PrimMonad m` _you_ choose, or just by restricting `m` to be `ST s`. Here's the [code](http://hpaste.org/80991). If this indeed does answer your problem, let me know and I'll write down an answer.

Comment: I do believe this works, with some minor changes. Make sure to add 'Rank2Types' to the language imports, and the rank2 type in `applyFunc` should be (forall m. (PrimMonad m) => ...) Many thanks! Rank2Types pulled through in the end.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot I had `RankNTypes` in `.ghci`. By the way, I believe `Rank2Types` is being deprecated in favour of `RankNTypes`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I've got a slight variant to ask. Apparently it matters whether the rank 2 forall'd function is in a *pair* or not. The actual type of applyFunc is: `(M.MVector v r, V.Vector v' r, v ~ Mutable v') =>
             (forall m . (PrimMonad m) => ((v (PrimState m) r -> v (PrimState m) r -> m ()), Int)) -> v' r -> v' r`. However, simply adding this pair (to keep track of size) results in the new error `couldn't match type m0 with 'ST s'` Why would adding the pair cause this? A GHC issue?

Comment: Do I really have to add the "ImpredicativeTypes" extension just to move the rank 2 quantifier inside the pair? That seems rather extreme for such a benign change. The new type for `applyFunc` is: `(M.MVector v r, V.Vector v' r, v ~ Mutable v') => ((forall m . (PrimMonad m) => ((v (PrimState m) r -> v (PrimState m) r -> m ()), Int) -> v' r -> v' r`. With ImpredicativeTypes, this compiles. Also, if this is a reasonable solution, Rank2/NTypes is no longer needed.

Comment: `ImpredicativeTypes` implies `RankNTypes`, so you need that extension anyways. But yes, if you want keep polymorphic functions inside some structure, you need either specialized data type (e.g. `newtype I = I (forall a. a -> a)`) or `ImpredicativeTypes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following type for `applyFunc` work for you?

```
applyFunc :: (Vector v a) => 
  (forall s. Mutable v s a -> Mutable v s a -> ST s ()) 
  -> v a -> v a
```

That should compile with out problem so long as you have the `Rank2Types` extension, which you need because you work with a function that has to work on *all* ST monads.  The reason for this is the type of `runST` is `(forall s. ST s a) -> a`, so the body of the code after `runST` needs to work for all `s`, hence `g` needs to work for all `s`.

(You could instead take a function that work with all `PrimMonads` but there are strictly fewer of those).

GHC can not infer higher rank types.  There are very good reasons to not infer `RankNTypes` (it is undecidable), and although `Rank2` is in theory inferable, the GHC people decided for the rule "infer if and only if the principle type is a Hindley-Milner type" which for people like me is very easy to reason about, and makes the compiler writers job not so hard.

In the comments you ask about taking a tuple.  Tuples with polymorphic types require `ImpredicativeTypes` and can be done like

```
applyFuncInt :: (Vector v a) => 
   ((forall s. Mutable v s a -> Mutable v s a -> ST s ()),Int)
   -> v a -> v a
applyFuncInt (g,_) x = runST $ do
                            y <- V.thaw x
                            g y y
                            V.unsafeFreeze y
```

although, usually it would be better to simply pass the number as a separate argument.